# SDWebImage cannot find SDImageCacheType

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdwebimage

I'm facing the problem that I cannot use completion block of the *SDWebImage* library (written in Objective-C). I'm using `sd_setImageWithURL` in several places, but every time I receive error *Use of undeclared type 'SDImageCacheType'*. The problem occured on 2 different MacBooks. I checked and the missing type is declared in `SDWebImage.h` file (attached at the end). I'm using CocoaPods.

[image: How it looks on XCode]

### Essencial source code

```
        imageViewMain.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: finalURL)) //Works fine

        // Doesn't work.
        let b : SDImageCacheType = SDImageCacheType.None
        let block = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType.None, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
            println(self)
        }
        imageViewMain.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: finalURL), completed: block)
```

### Briding header essential line

```
#import <SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h>
```

### The top of the `SDImageCache.h` file

```
/*
 * This file is part of the SDWebImage package.
 * (c) Olivier Poitrey <rs@dailymotion.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SDWebImageCompat.h"
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SDImageCacheType) {
    /**
     * The image wasn't available the SDWebImage caches, but was downloaded from the web.
     */
    SDImageCacheTypeNone,
    /**
     * The image was obtained from the disk cache.
     */
    SDImageCacheTypeDisk,
    /**
     * The image was obtained from the memory cache.
     */
    SDImageCacheTypeMemory
};
```

### Podfile

```
pod 'SDWebImage's'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: I faced with the same of your problem, did you fix it?

Comment: I did find, look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey that was a really trivial problem I don't know why I didn't figure it out earlier. All I need to do is to add one import. Looks like if you use declared blocks you need to add it.

```
import SDWebImage
```

Comment: 'import SDWebImage' is resolved the error. But I still don't know why import at Bridging-Header cannot use the completion block of SDWebimage? However, I still be able to use another function of the library.